# Show loader on click in the table on multiple instances

Tags: angular

What I am trying to achieve-
The table data is displayed using ngFor loop. Each table row has delete icon. If the user clicks on  delete icons it should show loaders on all the icons which are clicked. I defined an array clickedIndex = []; and storing the index i in that array because it keeps track of which table row  was clicked.
i am checking in the template which ngif to show i==clickedIndex[i] then show loader and so on.
It works if I start clicking on delete button from the top from the 0th index https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZYfN.png
It breaks if I click delete icon from anywhere in between https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqqjp.png I clicked on 2th index the 2 next to 0 you see is because of {{clickedIndex[i]}}

```
<table id="customers">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let file of uploadedFileHistory; let i=index;">
          <td>{{file.fileName}}</td>
          <td>{{file.createDateTime}}</td>
          <td>{{file.status}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="file.downloadToken; else notready;">
         ......
          </td>
          <ng-template #notready>
          <td>
        ......
          </td>
        </ng-template>
        <td>
          {{i}}
          {{clickedIndex[i]}}
          <div *ngIf="deleting && i==clickedIndex[i]" class="del-loader">loader is shown</div>
          <a *ngIf="deleting && i!=clickedIndex[i]" (click)="delFile(file.id, i)"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a *ngIf="!deleting" (click)="delFile(file.id, i)"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

.ts file

```
clickedIndex = [];
deleting: boolean;


 //When user clicks on delete icon
  delFile(id: any, index: any) {
    this.clickedIndex.push(index);
    alert(this.clickedIndex);
    alert(index);
    this.deleting = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.deleting = false;
    }, 15000);
    // let fileId = {
    //   userFileId: id
    // }
    // this.auth.deleteUserFile(fileId).subscribe((res: any)=>{
    //   this.auth.getUserFiles().subscribe((res)=>{
    //     this.deleting = false;
    //     this.uploadedFileHistory = res;
    //     this.noRecords = this.uploadedFileHistory.length === 0 ? true : false;
    //   });
    // },(err: any)=>{
    //   this.deleting = false;
    //  });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are testing a wrong predicate.

you are checking if `i` is the same as the value at `clickedIndex[i]` which means the value at index i in the array.

So

```
i = 1;
clickedIndex = [1,2]
```

then you are checking `1 === 2` because `clickedIndex[1] = 2`.

What you want to do is check for `clickedIndex.includes(i)`.

This will return truthy if your value is in the array.

[Array.Includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var i1 = 1;
var i2 = 2;
var clickedIndex = [];

clickedIndex.push(i1);
clickedIndex.push(i2);

var test = i1 == clickedIndex[i1]; // 1 == 2

console.log("i1:", i1);
console.log("Value at index i1:", clickedIndex[i1]);
console.log("predicate:", test);

console.log("With includes: ",clickedIndex.includes(i1))
```